# Powershell - Import-Csv row by row

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to use import CSV to import data into a website, the CSV which I am importing is below:

```
Yes Test    Test    Test            test@test.com   test    test    test    test    test    Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes 1   
Yes test2   test2   test2           test2@test2.com test2   test2   test2   test2   test2   Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes 2
```

The issue that I am facing is that if you take the second column for example, it will take both "Test" and "Test2" and place it into the field, like so:

[image]

I am struggling to find a way of going Row by Row.

```
$Header = 'Active Contact', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Position', 'Office', 'Mobile', 'Email Address', 'Site Name', 'Town', 'County', 'Authorised to make changes to this list?', 'Change', 'Commercial', 'Planned / Emergency Maintenance Notification?', 'Major Incident Notification?', 'Priority 1 Notification?', 'View All Portal Tickets?', 'Excalation', 'Contact'

function Create-Contact { 
    $products = import-csv 'C:\Users\Test\Desktop\CACL.csv' -Header $Header | Select -Skip 8
    ForEach-Object {
        write-host "Working on Contact: $iterator "

        #fill out form fields
        ($ie.document.getElementById("106009280") |select -first 1).value = $products.'First Name'; #Forename
        ($ie.document.getElementById("106009237") |select -first 1).value = $products.'Last Name'; #Surname
        ($ie.document.getElementById("106009289") |select -first 1).value = $products.'Position'; #Job Title
        ($ie.document.getElementById("106009283") |select -first 1).value = $products.'Office'; #Telephone
        ($ie.document.getElementById("106009286") |select -first 1).value = $products.'Mobile'; #Mobile
        ($ie.document.getElementById("106009416") |select -first 1).value = $products.'Email Address'; #Email

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; # Remove For Prod

        ($ie.document.getElementById("updateBtn") |select-first 1).click #Submit the new contact

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; # Remove For Prod

        $iterator ++

    }
}
Create-Contact
```

Comment: `$products` is an array, so you get an array when you access one of its members. It's also not clear what the `ForEach-Object` is iterating over. Please state clearly what outcome you want.

Comment: The First line of the CSV will be placed into a different fields on a website and then submitted, the second line will then be inputted into the website and submitted and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$products` is an array. When you access a member of the objects held in an array, powershell will return an array of those values. So

```
$products.'First Name'
```

returns an array of 2 strings (i.e. "Test Test2")

Based on your comment, in your case you can access the individual rows of the `$products` array by indexing:

```
$products[0].'First Name'
```

will return "Test".

Comment: This works perfectly thank you! Is there a way I can include it in the loop so that It will go over to the next row?

Comment: @Luke Do you mean alternate over the 2 rows at each iteration?

Comment: I mean read the next row on the next iteration and through each iteration move onto the next row